# Why would I lose water pressure in my house for several months after running the outside faucets?

Tags: plumbing

After using the water outside, the water pressure in my house goes way down. When we flush the toilet you can hear whistling in the pipes and sometimes bubbling like you would after the water has been turned off. We do not have a water pump so I know it is not that. The only thing I can think is that when we use the water outside it pulls some of the water from the pipes in the house and puts bubbles in them. But I don't know exactly how to fix it. Most of the time it just fixes itself after about a month or two, but I really don't want to wait that long to get my water pressure back.

I am on city/county water. There is no well. I am not sure what my pipes are made of but I think they are pvc. I live in a trailer and I know that the pipes under my trailer are pvc. The pipes coming to the house are about 13 years old.  Please let me know if this helps.

**Where would I check to see if it is a bad pressure regulator? Would that be on the water meter?**

Comment: Rusty iron pipes that clog because of a change in water flow patterns? I've seen these things neck down to 1/4" from rust, usually before rusting through and leaking. All it takes is some chunks in the wrong place. Also a bad pressure regulator?

Comment: a pressure reducing valve usually has a bell-like shape. http://www.homedepot.ca/product/water-pressure-reducing-valves/925272.  it would not be part of the meter and there is nothing guaranteeing that it is close by either, though in most cases they are.

Comment: @Ecnerwal In cases like this, please suggest a rollback to the previous revision (go to the post's history, find the revision you want and click the rollback link underneath it) and explain **clearly** that it's a rollback and why you're doing it, enough to convince the reviewers to approve your suggestion. Since you have less than 2000 rep, you'll get +2 for an approved edit, and there are various badges for editing posts too.

Comment: Not so easy to find, but I figured out where to access revision in edits, finally. Still don't see a rollback button (I think I have seen it for my OWN edits on other SE sites)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I didn't realize that rollback isn't available until you reach 2000 rep. There's an easy workaround: click edit on the post, then select the right revision from the dropdown. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121826/146318

Answer (score 1):

> that when we use the water outside it pulls some of the water from the 
>   pipes in the house and puts bubbles in them.

I'm not quite seeing the bizarre method by which this would take a month to clear out, but I think I see at least part of the problem - probably something like a defective vacuum breaker on the exterior faucet **is** somehow doing exactly that - putting air in your pipes.

If that air remains trapped for some reason (weird configuration of the pipes) it could result in a situation where you have a section of pipe with a trapped air bubble and a little bit of water running in it. This is not particularly common, in my experience - normally air in the pipes comes very noisily out the faucet the first time you turn it on - but to get your symptoms I have to speculate that somehow it stays trapped, and then over the course of a month of using the water with lousy water pressure, it's gradually dissolving the air into the water and carrying it out of the pipe, until finally the bubble is gone and you get normal pressure.

Mind you, it's also bizarre enough that it could be some other thing, but this would fit the air bubbles heard and the month-long recovery. And it may well mean that there is something else wrong for it to be able to happen in the first place, but I can't quite picture what that might be.

You might try removing an aerator on one of your faucets (reduces the restriction there, will let the water run faster) to see if that will help "burp" the air out faster. i.e., you'd see & hear bubbles coming out of the faucet if it was working - don't just leave it off for a month - if it doesn't work in a few minutes, it's not going to help.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. I am about to my whits end with this.  Right now it have been over a month and it is still doing it. I am hoping it will clear up soon.